# Database Design (DDL)

Tags: database-design, rdbms, ddl

I've got a table for ice cream shops (parlor) and a table for the different flavours offered in a parlor. In addition there is a user table and a user should be able to rate flavours.

There is a one-to-many relationship between Parlor and flavour, where flavour is a weak entity. There is also a many-to-many relationship between Flavour and User, which then creates a new table called Vote.

My DDL-Script looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE parlor (
    parlor_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    street VARCHAR(255),
    street_numb INTEGER,
    zip INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (parlor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE flavour (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    parlor_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, parlor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parlor_id) REFERENCES parlor (parlor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    password BINARY(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

CREATE TABLE vote (
    date TIMESTAMP,
    ranking INTEGER(5),
    flavour VARCHAR(255),
    uid INTEGER,
    parlor_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (date, uid, flavour, parlor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user (uid),
    FOREIGN KEY (flavour) REFERENCES flavour (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (parlor_id) REFERENCES flavour (parlor_id)
);
```

My problem is, that I'm able to vote for a flavour that doesn't even exist in a parlor. For example:

```
INSERT INTO vote (date, ranking, flavour, uid, parlor_id) VALUES ('...', 5, 'Chocolate', 1, 10)
```

In a parlor with the ID 10, a user with the userID 1 rates the flavour 'Chocolate' with 5.

But when I do ...

```
SELECT * FROM flavour WHERE parlor_id=10;
```

there is no flavour 'chocolate'

Comment: How are users associated with a parlor? Is it where they buy a flavor? Can't users buy from different parlors? Is there something different about a flavor from different parlors or is chocolate from Parlor A the same as chocolate from Parlor B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an actual key to the flavors table (`flavor_id INTEGER`), set that as the primary key and have foreign keys reference that column. This will sort it your problem and improve your overall design.

You can "convert" your `name, parlor_id` key to a unique constraint to maintain uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your flavour PK is (name, parlor_id), but vote references only part of it:

```
FOREIGN KEY (flavour) REFERENCES flavour (name)
```

Of course your could do a complex FK:

```
FOREIGN KEY (flavour, parlour_id) REFERENCES flavour (name, parlour_id)
```

But actually it would be better if you simply use regular PK on flavour:

```
CREATE TABLE flavour (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    parlor_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (parlor_id) REFERENCES parlor (parlor_id)
);
```

And reference this ID:

```
CREATE TABLE vote (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date TIMESTAMP,
    ranking INTEGER(5),
    flavour_id INTEGER,
    uid INTEGER,
    parlor_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user (uid),
    FOREIGN KEY (flavour_id) REFERENCES flavour (id)
);
```